# Why does (read-event) fail to show prompt?

Tags: untagged

I am having a problem with the built-in function `read-event` and I'd like to make sure I am using it in the proper manner before reporting this as a bug.

Here is a description of my problem:

1. In the `*scratch*` buffer I type
   `(read-event "Press any key")`
2. With the cursor at the end of the above line I press `C-x` `C-e` in order to execute this command.
3. If I type these two keys in rapid succession, the command executes as expected, but in case there is a delay of a few seconds in between the pressing of `C-x` and `C-e`,
   the prompt "Press any key" is not shown and instead the minibuffer shows `C-x C-e-` while waiting for the next event.

My questions are thus:  (1) Can you reproduce this undesired behavior?  Can you spot anything I might be doing wrong?

The above is a description of a minimal instance where I noticed
the above behavior.  In my real life situation a combination of
keys is used to invoke a function which in turn involves the
`read-event` function.  If there is a delay in between pressing
the calling keys, the prompt fails to show.

My emacs version is the latest stable one, I believe, namely `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2022-01-24`

Comment: I can reproduce this in 27.2, but not in 28.2.  Seems like a bug which was fixed.

Comment: 28.2 is the latest stable release, but that version may not be in your OS package repository.

Comment: While I haven't personally tested it, @phils' insight is valid.  If you encounter issues with the older versions, it's advisable to test it in the latest stable release before asking your question.

Comment: Thanks @phils!  Indeed I do not yet have access to 28.2 through my repository.  Guess I'll have to wait a bit.

Comment: If it's a Debian-based system then https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs is likely an option.